# Probability question, choosing a random integer number from [0, a]

Tags: probability

Every time choosing a random integer number from [0, a], what is the probability of after k times, the sum of all chosen numbers is greater or equal to b.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! please show what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

In [this query](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3876263/find-the-number-of-triples-k-1-k-2-k-3-of-integers-such-that)
compare the methods used in the answers of user2661923
[me : stars and bars + Inclusion-Exclusion]
and Yip Jung Hon [generating polynomials].

I think that you should specify in your query whether $a$ and $b$ are integers.  Note that you have to count the polynomial solutions for each possible value of $b$.  Presumably, the possible sums will range from $0$ through $a \times k$ inclusive.

Each collection of random integers is equally likely, as is each non-negative integer solution $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = b.$

The math here is (in my opinion) extremely ugly.